# DJANGO REST web login not working with JWT if permission set to IsAuthenticated

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

The rest framework has its default web-based API-authentication

```
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
```

However, once JWT authentication is added and the permission is set to IsAuthenticated, you can no longer use the default or built-in API authentication.

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

I tried logging in but it still prompted me with the error message above.

Currently, I am building my project with no front end or client, just the API. So the default or templates provided by Django Rest Framework and Django itself is what I am currently using

Is there a way to solve this one? I know you have to attach the access token with your login credentials, so how can you do this with the default authentication of rest?

Also when you add the following code the problem above can be solved. However, I do not know if this is the proper way to solve it.

```
'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
```

Screenshots for context:

[Django Rest Framework with Login (indicating I am not logged yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubNIE.png)

[Django Rest Default or built-in login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ggZ7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your rest framework authentication_classes like the following code:

```
'REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    
]
```

I'm not sure if it solves the problem because I heard from an experienced Django developer that the login system of Django and the rest framework are different than the custom login system we write. In that fact, you have to attach a JWT token anyway.

Comment: yes I did and still not working

`
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
}
`